# How To Show Data in Recycler View Card View with SQLite in fragment Xamarin Android Native

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am new in Xamarin and Android. I want to show my data from SQLITE to recycler view cardview with xamarin android in fragment. I found an example there https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/xamarin-android-recyclerv/ and literally, I want to achieve like the link but, it don't use SQLite and not in fragment. I want to show the photo in the recycler view cardview. I already search in internet but, I still don't get what I want. I've tried but still stuck. and let me show my code 
**in main.xml**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView" 
    android:scrollbars="vertical" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

in my foodcardview

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="8dp">
                <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="250dp"
                        android:layout_height="180dp"
                        android:id="@+id/imgfood"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="100dp"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#333333"
                        android:id="@+id/foodtitle"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"/>
                <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#333333"
                        android:id="@+id/fooddesc"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"/>
        <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                        android:textColor="#ffffff"
                        android:id="@+id/foodphotopath"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

I know it's simple and I am noob. Would you like to help me? I really appreciated! Thank in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write a demo about your needs, Here is running screenshot.

[image]

I used `Fragments`(contains `RecycleView`) with `Viewpager`, `sqlite` to achieve it.

First of all, If U used ImageView to show the Image. you should know how to store the image. Use Base64String or imagePath, I used Base64String to store string to the Sqlite DB. Here is my Util class.It could convert Bitmap to string And convert string to bitmap.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace BottomNavigation
{
    public class MyUtils
    {
        public static string ConvertBitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap)
        {

            byte[] bitmapData;
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitmap.Compress(Android.Graphics.Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 50, stream);
                bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
            }

            string ImageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bitmapData);

            return ImageBase64;
        }

        public static Bitmap ConvertStringToBitmap(string mystr)
        {
            byte[] decodedString = Base64.Decode(mystr, Base64Flags.Default);
            Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.Length);

            return decodedByte;
        }
    }
}
```

In the Install tag, I init the sqlite DB, because this tab have a first display `Fragment`.

```
  public static void DoSomeDataAccess()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Creating database, if it doesn't already exist");
            string dbPath = Path.Combine(
                 System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal),
                 "ormdemo.db3");
            db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
            db.CreateTable<MyModel>();


            if (db.Table<MyModel>().Count() == 0)
            {
                // only insert the data if it doesn't already exist
                var newStock = new MyModel();
                newStock.ImageBase64String = @"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";
                ;
                newStock.Name = "test1";
                newStock.Descirption = "this is a description";
                db.Insert(newStock);
                newStock = new MyModel();
                newStock.ImageBase64String =@"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";
                ;
                newStock.Name = "test2";
                newStock.Descirption = "this is a description";
                db.Insert(newStock);
                newStock = new MyModel();
                newStock.ImageBase64String = @"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";
                ;
                newStock.Name = "test3";
                newStock.Descirption = "this is a description";
                db.Insert(newStock);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Reading data");
          //  var table = db.Table<MyModel>();

        }
```

I create a model called `MyModel`. you can add other properties that you needed.

```
 [Table("Items")]
    public class MyModel
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("_id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string ImageBase64String { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Descirption { get; set; }
    }
```

`NewsFragment.cs` contains `RecycleView`. `MyAdapter.cs` is a `RecyclerView.Adapter`.

Other code you can refer to my demo, here is my demo link.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-KAG8xO26nmrPpabv9wRMzrPadhaX1oh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you! You help me a lot!! Well, As a beginner it takes more time for me to understand the codes. Btw, why you use `viewpager` for the fragment? I wanna know the reason from you because, I am noob

Comment: `viewpager` is container, it contains three fragments, when you click the three tabs in the bottom of screen, fragments will change, If you want to make your application to running in a tablet, this way will make the fragments transfer more fluently.